# Issue with In app purchase in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have impelmented in app purchase in my app.I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial)

Now in my app when i try load products then it does not load.It shows error as can't connect to iTunes store.I have craeted one product on iTunes.

Below is the code

```
/

    *
    * Copyright (c) 2016 Razeware LLC
    *
    * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
    *
    * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
    * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
    *
    * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
    * THE SOFTWARE.
    */

    import StoreKit

    public typealias ProductIdentifier = String
    public typealias ProductsRequestCompletionHandler = (_ success: Bool, _ products: [SKProduct]?) -> ()

    open class IAPHelper : NSObject  {

      static let IAPHelperPurchaseNotification = "IAPHelperPurchaseNotification"
      fileprivate let productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>
      fileprivate var purchasedProductIdentifiers = Set<ProductIdentifier>()
      fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
      fileprivate var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

      public init(productIds: Set<ProductIdentifier>) {
        productIdentifiers = productIds
        for productIdentifier in productIds {
          let purchased = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: productIdentifier)
          if purchased {
            purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(productIdentifier)
            print("Previously purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
          } else {
            print("Not purchased: \(productIdentifier)")
          }
        }
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
      }

    }

    // MARK: - StoreKit API

    extension IAPHelper {

      public func requestProducts(completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
        productsRequest?.cancel()
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
        productsRequest!.delegate = self
        productsRequest!.start()
      }

      public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
        print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
        let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
      }

      public func isProductPurchased(_ productIdentifier: ProductIdentifier) -> Bool {
        return purchasedProductIdentifiers.contains(productIdentifier)
      }

      public class func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
      }

      public func restorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
      }
    }

    // MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

    extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate {

      public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let products = response.products
        print("Loaded list of products...")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
        clearRequestAndHandler()

        for p in products {
          print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
        }
      }

      public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to load list of products.")
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
        clearRequestAndHandler()
      }

      private func clearRequestAndHandler() {
        productsRequest = nil
        productsRequestCompletionHandler = nil
      }
    }

    // MARK: - SKPaymentTransactionObserver

    extension IAPHelper: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

      public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
          switch (transaction.transactionState) {
          case .purchased:
            complete(transaction: transaction)
            break
          case .failed:
            fail(transaction: transaction)
            break
          case .restored:
            restore(transaction: transaction)
            break
          case .deferred:
            break
          case .purchasing:
            break
          }
        }
      }

      private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("complete...")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
      }

      private func restore(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        guard let productIdentifier = transaction.original?.payment.productIdentifier else { return }

        print("restore... \(productIdentifier)")
        deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: productIdentifier)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
      }

      private func fail(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {
        print("fail...")
        if let transactionError = transaction.error as? NSError {
          if transactionError.code != SKError.paymentCancelled.rawValue {
            print("Transaction Error: \(transaction.error?.localizedDescription)")
          }
        }

        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
      }

      private func deliverPurchaseNotificationFor(identifier: String?) {
        guard let identifier = identifier else { return }

        purchasedProductIdentifiers.insert(identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: identifier)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: IAPHelper.IAPHelperPurchaseNotification), object: identifier)
      }
    }
```

Please guide what is the issue ?

EDIT:
Did fail with error is getting called."Failed to load list of products."

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Not getting products

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have signed out of any production iTunes accounts on the device.

I was getting this error on my test phone which was logged in with my actual iTunes account. **You cannot test apps using your production iTunes account**, hence the error. I just wish Apple provided a better error so as to avoid this guesswork...

**The solution** is to **create a test user account** if you don't have one. Test in-app purchase using that account.

**Note:** If in case, you are not getting products, please make sure that you are using product identifier while sending request exactly that matches with the product identifier on itunes.

Another silly reason, we encounter this error when we run on simulator. Check whether

> Your app is running in the Simulator, which does not support In-App
>   Purchase

Comment: do i need to login with tester account for product

Comment: do i need to login with tester account for getting products –

Comment: Yes. Otherwise you can't test in-app purchase

Comment: I created one sandbox user when i enter my details then it says itunes account creation not allowed

Comment: Not able to create test user?

Comment: You need credit card information to be entered. Did you fill that before you are creating test user?

Comment: This link says i do not have to enter any account logged in to teh app

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: What is the problem you are facing in creating account? can you please specify more?

Comment: You create the sandbox user in iTunesConnect. You can't create a sandbox user on the device  as you can with a normal user

Answer (score 0):

After logging out of the iTunes & iCloud account i reset my iOS device & In app purchase worked.Although i don't know why.

You don't have to be logged in to iOS device for getting products from in app purchase.For buying the products then we must be logged into the device.